# Generating variable for ng-class dynamically using Expression in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive

Here is snippet from my HTML code.

```
<div ng-repeat="boxName in boxNameList">
    <div ng-class="myBoxes.{{boxName}}">{{boxName}}</div>
</div>
```

**What I am trying to do:**
I have created 3 div elements which will be at the top of a screen using the above written snippet. Each div element will be given a shape of a box using css. A box(div) can have either red color as its background or black color as its background.

CSS for the two colors is:

```
.redBackground{
   background-color: red;
}

.blackBackground{
  background-color: black;
}
```

Here is a snippet from my controller:

```
$scope.boxNameList=['Box1','Box2','Box3'];
$scope.myBoxes={
      Box1: "redBackground",
      Box2: "blackBackground",
      Box3: "blackBackground"
}
```

In this example I have made `$scope.myBoxes` as a static Json but at runtime I plan to generate Json code so that I can dynamically assign background colors to my boxes.

**Problem that I am facing:** Well the problem is that I am not able to see the boxes with colors at all. The ng-class variable name in this case as you can see is also generated dynamically. If I do not use ng-repeat and do not dynamically generate ng-class variable name then it works fine. For e.g for the snippet given below when I dynamically change the value of the varibales `myBoxes.Box1`  `myBoxes.Box2` and `myBoxes.Box3` then it works perfectly.

```
<div ng-class="myBoxes.Box1">Box1</div>
<div ng-class="myBoxes.Box2">Box2</div>
<div ng-class="myBoxes.Box3">Box3</div>
```

However if I generate the ng-class variable dynamically `"myBoxes.{{boxName}}"` then it doesn't behave like a variable. I am sure there would be a better way to achieve what I am trying to do however I was not able to find that after hours and hours of googling/trial and error. Would be glad if someone could help me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're almost there, it's `myBoxes[boxName]` and not `myBoxes.{{boxName}}`.

Something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.boxNameList=['Box1','Box2','Box3'];
        $scope.myBoxes={
              Box1: "redBackground",
              Box2: "blackBackground",
              Box3: "blackBackground"
        }
    }]);
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .redBackground{
       background-color: red;
    }

    .blackBackground{
      background-color: black;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="name in boxNameList">
        <div ng-class="myBoxes[name]">Box1</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awesome! works like a charm. But I still wonder why it worked by accessing the Json object values using array notation instead of the normal way of accessing Json objects using dot notation.
I am a javscript newbie, I apologize if I am asking a very fundamental question.

Comment: First off, `myBoxes.{{boxName}}` isn't a valid expression in Angular, but `myBoxes.boxName` and `myBoxes[boxName]` are. In Javascript, these expressions are the same: `myBoxes.boxName`, `myBoxes['boxName']` and `var name = 'boxName'; myBoxes[name];` which means that when you want a property on an object but you don't know what the property name is, you can use array notation with a variable instead.

Comment: Edit:
oh! then in that case `{{'myBoxes.' + name}}` should also work for me since it is a valid angular js expression. But it doesn't work for me.

Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Yes, you could, but if you use {{expr}} in ng-class, the expression won't be re-evaluated later. See the difference here: http://jsfiddle.net/DwpXs/

Comment: Can't seem to get it working. I have an array of objects, like: {name: 'christina', gender: 'female'}. I tried doing ng-repeat="person in people" and inside ng-class="person['gender']" but can't get the .female class attached.