# How to decorate ng-repeat element with ng-class etc

Tags: angularjs

I have an element:

I'd like to use

ng-class="{ 'children'+level.length }" (or something like this, i.e to output a class that has the number of levels. Is it possible to do it on this iterating element?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="level in levels">
    <p ng-class="{'children' : level.length == 1}">test</p>
</div>
```

`ng-class` simply takes an expression.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to use a function in your ng-class.

```
  $scope.levelClass = function(i){
      return "level"+i;
  }
```

and then

```
ng-class="levelClass(children.level)"
```

Check out this question for other solutions
[Generating variable for ng-class dynamically using Expression in AngularJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020189/generating-variable-for-ng-class-dynamically-using-expression-in-angularjs)