# Applying a class dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, class

I know similar question have been asked before and I have gone through many but not getting the class to be applied.

I have the following:

```
data-ng-class="doc.documentCategory ? doc.documentCategory.toLowerCase() : '' "
```

Trying to apply a class depending on the value of the doc.documentary variable.
I have tried:

```
   data-ng-class="[doc.documentCategory ? doc.documentCategory.toLowerCase() : '']"
    data-ng-class="{doc.documentCategory ? doc.documentCategory.toLowerCase() : ''}"
```

and read:
[dynamic classname Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090877/dynamic-classname-inside-ngclass-in-angular-2) [class name variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643836/dynamic-class-in-angular-js) [changing class name based on variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020189/generating-variable-for-ng-class-dynamically-using-expression-in-angularjs)

and others. Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ng-class="{'Class1': doc.documentCategory == doc.documentCategory.toLowerCase()}"
```

The class will be only applied when the condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using the following:

data-ng-class="doc.documentCategory ? doc.documentCategory.toLowerCase() : ''"

It worked !

Answer (score -1):

Is this angularjs, or angular 2/4? There is some ambiguity because of the linked answers.

If the latter, then `[ngClass] = "doc.documentCategory ? doc.documentCategory.toLowerCase() : ''"` should work?